# Bean Validation: Complex message value resolution - but how?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I've written a custom constraint called `@Year` which checks whether a `Date` occurs in a certain year.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = YearCheck.class)
public @interface Year {

  String message() default "{year.message}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  /**
   * The lower year. If not specified then no upper boundary check is performed.<br>
   * Special values are:
   * <ul>
   * <li>{@link TimeUtil#NOW} for the current year
   * </ul>
   */
  String min() default "";

  /**
   * The upper year. If not specified then no upper boundary check is performed.<br>
   * Special values are:
   * <ul>
   * <li>{@link TimeUtil#NOW} for the current year
   * </ul>
   */
  String max() default "";
}
```

The `ValidationMessages.properties` contain the following:

```
year.message = must be a year between {min} and {max}
```

As you can see, `min` and `max` are Strings, because `TimeUtil.NOW` (a constant containing `"now"`) means that the current year is taken for the comparison.

Also, if `min` or `max` is not specified, it means, the corresponding value is *infinity*

So, the question is, for instance for `min`: How can I check whether `min` has been set and if's not a number (either `""` or `"now"`) how can I set a value which will then be inserted into the message?

For instance `@Year(min=1900,max=TimeUtil.NOW)` should generate the message

```
must be a year between 1900 and 2013
```

I've read some answers on stackoverflow, read the documentation, but I'm not sure whether a) it's possible and b) I need to do this in the constraint implementation or a custom `MessageInterpolator`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check whether min has been set and if's not a number

You can access the annotation attributes in the `initialize()` method of your `ConstraintValidator` implementation.

> how can I set a value which will then be inserted into the message?

You can't directly do this, but you could create the message yourself in the `isValid()` method of your validator using the passed `ConstraintValidatorContext`.

Altogether your validator might look like this:

```
public class YearValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Year, String> {

    private Date min;
    private Date max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Year constraintAnnotation) {
        if(constraintAnnotation.min().equals("")) {
            min = getMinimumDate();
        }
        else if(constraintAnnotation.min().equals(TimeUtil.NOW)) {
            min = getCurrentYear();
        }
        else {
            min = getYearFromString(constraintAnnotation.min());
        }

        //same for max()
}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Date value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if(value.before(min) || value.after(max)) {

            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

            //load/create the error message and set min and max in it
            String template = getTemplate(min, max);

            context
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(template)
                .addConstraintViolation();

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gunnar! Thanks for the extensive answer! The problem however is the `getTemplate(min, max)` part: `context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()` will return `"{year.message}"`, but how can I access the String, especially since I have my own `ResourceBundleLocator`? Anyway, if I understand your answer correctly, there is no way to intercept the message building at this level? For instance that I could set the values of `{min}` and `{max}` myself.

Comment: I also tried to write my own `MessageInterpolator`, but `context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes()` is an `UnmodifiableMap`. Do I have to clone the `Context` and create my own attributes?

Comment: Setting the values yourself is indeed not possible. For accessing the String, you could just load a `ResourceBundle` yourself.

Comment: Well, I would need the `ResourceBundle` of the `Validator`. Is there any way to get that? Also, I looked around the net about my message problem, and there are a lot of similar requests. So do you think that https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-233 would solve my problem? And if did, it would probably appear in HV 6, right?

Comment: Assuming you have stored your message in `ValidationMessages.properties`, you would get a resource bundle like this: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("ValidationMessages");`. I'm not sure about BVAL-233, but [BVAL-339](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-339) might indeed address your problem. You may raise your voice for this on the BV [mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/beanvalidation-dev).

Comment: Thanks, I now signed up in the Hibernate JIRA and voted for both issues.